# Hibernate, Cascaded operations, Duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a many to many relation between 2 tables Person and Address with a middle table Person_Address. I have Daos and Services for these entities

What i want to have is when a person is added with an address list if the addresses already exists in the database system should just add id's of those addresses to the Person_Address table.

What happens is duplicate values with different ids.

Possible way to do this is to check the database before adding but if i were to do that then i would be writing my own SQL queries instead of hibernate. Is there a way for me to achieve my objective in hibernate?

Person Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "personID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surName;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ADDRESS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PERSONID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESSID")})
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Address Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "addressID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "addresses")
    private List<Person> residents;
    private String street;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String postCode;
```

Comment: There's no way to do this, that I know of. If you pass in an entity for persist without an 'id' it will get a new one. So, if you provide an Address that already exists to a Person, make sure that that address has an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Entity have no ID. Hibernate creates it differently updates.

You should use prefilling of Address in frontend. Or use Criteria API for searching of entered of Address before saving

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one solution can be to change your database and set the complete adress as the primary key, you can get it by concatenating the others fields. To be sure that the adresses will be identical i think you will have to format it to lower or to upper case.
So when you will put the adresse it will be the primary key and you will not have duplicate datas.